# How do i slice a series in python?

Tags: python

How do i slice a series to retrieve the last 3 characters?

The series look like this:

```
1       WHITNEY ROU
2         ABBY  WAM
3         YAEL  AVE
```

I tried data["Names"][:-3] to get `ROU`,`WAM` and `AVE` but failed to do so.

Comment: So what did you get as result?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a series with the last 3 letters of the Names column of your `data` dataframe.

```py
last_three = data.Names.apply(lambda x: x[-3:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You only missed to call `.str` on your series.

```
>>> new_series = data["Names"].str[-3:]
>>> print(new_series)
0    ROU
1    WAM
2    AVE
```